# .NET 7 C# worker application logging to Elasticsearch using serilog

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, serilog, .net-7.0

I develop a worker application and I use Serilog to log errors on Elasticsearch, I get many problems:

1- when I throw exception the message template is unified but I need to
log other specific data with throw message, how can I do that?

2- the app throw exception every one minute, how can I restart it after
first throw?

I try to add proprieties to the message and log it as Error, that help me to log error one time and the background services still running, but I lost the stack trace of exception.

Comment: 2 - Why not fix the code so that it doesn't throw an exception every minute.  That sounds like a bug (or a rubbish feature).

Comment: it not a bug, by example the error has been thrown when calling external API, so the code still trying and throw the same exception.
I want to throw error but not stop the worker that is listening to other messages.

Comment: If the external service is expected to throw such exceptions - handle them, log them manually (with whatever info you want and at whatever level you want) and move on.